# How to format a date received from my server using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I need to format a date with javascript but I'm having a little trouble solving this.

I get two dates, I need to format them and then join the values.
On one of the dates I get this:

```
"2022-07-12T04:00:00-0300"
```

And on the other date I get this:

```
"2022-07-12T06:00:00-0300"
```

These are always dynamic dates returned from my backend, but here on the frontend I need to display these two dates in this following format:

```
"04:00 - 06:00"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is assuming you only need the hours and minutes.

```
function datesToRange(start, end) {
  if (!start || !end) return ""; // If either date is null or undefined.
  return start.substring(12, 17) + " - " + end.substring(12, 17);
}
```

Now you can call this method to get the range in your required format.

E.g.

```
datesToRange("2022-07-12T04:00:00-0300", "2022-07-12T06:00:00-0300");
```

Will return `"04:00 - 06:00"`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `slice()` method.

```js
var date1 = "2022-07-12T04:00:00-0300";
var date2 = "2022-07-12T06:00:00-0300";

var formatted = `${date1.slice(11, 16)} - ${date2.slice(11, 16)}`;

console.log(formatted);
```